# Simple multiprocessing/threading example in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

What's the differences between module *threading*, *Thread*, *multiprocessing*? (may be I have badly understood the conceptual differences between multithreads (share memory and global variables?) and multiprocesses (truly independant processes?

Could you please use to illustrate this simple example (calculus doesn't matter):
I have a loop that performs independant calculus that I wish to accelerate through parallel calculus:

```
def myfunct(d):
  facto = 1
  for x in range(d):
    facto*=x
  return facto


cases = [1,2,3,4] # and so on
for d in cases:  #loop to parallelize 
  print myfunct(d)  # or to store on a common list when calculated
```

thanks for your incoming pedagogical answers.

Answer (score 2):

No need for answers beyond the documentation

> """multiprocessing is a package that
>   supports spawning processes using an
>   API similar to the threading module.
>   The multiprocessing package offers
>   both local and remote concurrency,
>   effectively side-stepping the Global
>   Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses
>   instead of threads. Due to this, the
>   multiprocessing module allows the
>   programmer to fully leverage multiple
>   processors on a given machine. It runs
>   on both Unix and Windows. """

threading is about threads
multiprocessing about processes

What else is needed?